# VBA errors when trying to copy to the bottom of active section with one line

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using the following code in vba to copy what is in one cell down to the bottom of the active workbook.

```
Range("C3").Select

 LR = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
Range("C2").AutoFill Range("C2:C" & LR)
```

If I only have one line in the active sheet I get this error message.

Run-time error '1004
Autfill method of range class failed

it crashes on this line

```
Range("J2").AutoFill Range("J2:J" & LR)
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to add to avoid the error.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should post more of the code to make it clear what you are doing, I assume you are stepping from column to column and filling down with whatever is in row 2 of the column. the problem is if you have only one line (I assume you mean line 2) then your range is C2:C2 which you cannot autofill. use something like:

```
 LR = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
If LR = 2 then LR = 8
Range("C2").AutoFill Range("C2:C" & LR)
```

replacing 8 with whatever value makes sense.
If that is not the solution please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am coping what is in C3 down to the bottom of the active sheet.  Some times it is a vlookkup sometimes it is a concentrate or a If statement,  I need all the rows to do the same for all active rows.  I have used a copy like clicking on the small box in the bottom right corner and put the number at 5000 down but then when I copy and paste that column into another sheet to make labels I have a lot more rows to deal with.